# What basic example I can give for inner join and outer join in SQL?

Tags: mysql

Please help me to understand and best example for my question.

I can not understand how to create the object and use them.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have 2 tables:

```
ID  Name
1   Smith
2   Novak
3   Tarantino
```

and the second table

```
ID  Cash
2   300
3   490
4   500
```

`INNER JOIN` will join records that have match in both tables, i.e. in the result table only `ID` 2 and 3 will be included, because they have match.
Result would look like:

```
ID  Name       Cash
2   Novak      300
3   Tarantino  490
```

`OUTER JOIN` on the other hand, will match everything, irrespectively whether they have match or not. If record doesn't have match, then value corresponiding to certain row will be `NULL`, i.e. Smith will have `NULL` in `Cash` column and record corresponding to 500 in `Cash` column will have `NULL` in `Name` column.
Result would look like:

```
ID  Name       Cash
1   Smith      NULL
2   Novak      300
3   Tarantino  490
4   NULL       500
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Her some super simple stuff:

Prepare DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `value` text not null DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `value` text not null DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (5, 'five');

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
(3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (5, 'five'), (6, 'six'), (7, 'seven');
```

Execute queries:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
+----+-------+----+-------+
| id | value | id | value |
+----+-------+----+-------+
|  3 | three |  3 | three |
|  4 | four  |  4 | four  |
|  5 | five  |  5 | five  |
+----+-------+----+-------+
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
+----+-------+------+-------+
| id | value | id   | value |
+----+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | one   | NULL | NULL  |
|  2 | two   | NULL | NULL  |
|  3 | three |    3 | three |
|  4 | four  |    4 | four  |
|  5 | five  |    5 | five  |
+----+-------+------+-------+
```